404 error when accessing actuator/prometheus endpoint
In my spring boot application. I added following dependencies:
spring-boot-starter-actuator
micrometer-registry-prometheus

In application.properties file I added following code:
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus

When I access following url: http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus
I get 404 error. I am able to access http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
http://localhost:8080/actuator/inf endpoints. 

How can I fix this issue ? I looked at several post on stack over. None seems to be helping. This is the first time, I am trying Java spring boot application.
Spring security is enabled and user is authenticated using JWT token. I have disabled security, even then I am getting 404 error when accessing this endpoint

To make this work, I had to make these two changes.
added new dependency:
implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus-simpleclient', version: '1.13.4'

Changed the port for actuator in application.properties file:
management.server.port = 9095

Both changes are required
